# NamedVirtualHost in apache configuration

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have a unix system whose actual name is "ech-10.45.25.12"
i have installed apache server in it. 
Now i need to configure it in such a way that the two applications running in the same machine in tomcat in two different ports should be accessed by the same domain.

ie., i have two applications running in the same machine under different port

```
http://ech-10.45.25.12:8080/issuetracker/

http://ech-10.45.25.12:8180/dashboard/
```

I would like to name this server(ech-10.45.25.12) as devjunior.mycompany.com
The following is the configuration i have made in httpd.conf

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080
Listen 8180

NameVirtualHost ech-10.45.25.12:80
NameVirtualHost ech-10.45.25.12:8080
NameVirtualHost ech-10.45.25.12:8180

<VirtualHost ech-10.45.25.12:80>
ServerName devjunior.mycompany.com
DocumentRoot /www/domain-80
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost ech-10.45.25.12:8080>
ServerName devjunior.mycompany.com
DocumentRoot /www/domain-8080
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost ech-10.45.25.12:8180>
ServerName devjunior.mycompany.com
DocumentRoot /www/domain-8080
</VirtualHost>
```

i know i am doing a major mistake

But i should be able to access the applications by using the following urls

```
http://devjunior.mycompany.com/issuetracker
http://devjunior.mycompany.com/dashboard
```

Should i create ANY directories under any folders any where in the system
Please tell that also.

Comment: Probably is a typo: you repeated domain-8080 in the 8180 virtualhost rule

Answer (score 0):

You configured only the names. So you've configured Apache to listen for:

```
http://devjunior.mycompany.com:8080
http://devjunior.mycompany.com:8180
```

You can:

1. Configure 2 domains with namevirtualhost without using ports. **this is the most elegant way of doing what you want**
2. Configure a single domain that points to a single directory on the filesystem with 2 links for the diferrent applications. This works with php mostly or pure html pages. With more complex applications you could incur in a lot of headache..
3. Domain and port. Like you've done. But you can access only by `http://devjunior.mycompany.com:8080/issuetracker` and `http://devjunior.mycompany.com:8180/dashboard`

## Solution 1

You can use different domains or subdomains (which are cookie friendly in an eventuality of single sign on).

```
Listen 80

NameVirtualHost ech-10.45.25.12:80

<VirtualHost ech-10.45.25.12:80>
ServerName devjunior.mycompany.com
DocumentRoot /www/domain-80
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost ech-10.45.25.12:80>
ServerName dashboard.devjunior.mycompany.com
DocumentRoot /www/domain-8080
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost ech-10.45.25.12:80>
ServerName issuetracker.devjunior.mycompany.com
DocumentRoot /www/domain-8180
</VirtualHost>
```

*Solution 2 is left as an excercise for the reader... :P*

Comment: which solution are you proposing?

Comment: @user3519122 solution 1 for me is the most elegant as i said in the answer.. but depends on your company/requirements

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did to make it work.
Though the change of name in etc/hosts file did nothing in my intranet, so i used the actual name of the machine which is ech-10.45.25.12

```
NameVirtualHost ech-10.45.25.12:80

<VirtualHost ech-10.45.25.12:80>

   ServerName ech-10.45.25.12
   ProxyPreserveHost on
   ProxyPass /issuetracker http://ech-10.45.25.12:8080/issuetracker
   ProxyPass /dashboard http://ech-10.45.25.12:8180/dashboard

</VirtualHost>
```

Also dont forget to add the "proxyName" & "proxyPort" attribute to the  tag in tomcat's server.xml